# R parallel abort all mclapply operations

Tags: r, parallel-processing, mclapply

Is it possible to request that `parallel::mclapply()` abandons all further processing asap if it encounters an error (e.g., a `stop()`) in any one of its processes?

Comment: yikes.  I mean stopifnot.  (I just renamed my own.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another approach: The idea is to modify `parallel::mclapply()` at the three places indicated with `#!!`. The new argument `stop.on.error` can be used to specify whether the execution should stop when an error occurs.

```
library(parallel)
Mclapply <- function (X, FUN, ..., mc.preschedule = TRUE,
                      mc.set.seed = TRUE, mc.silent = FALSE,
                      mc.cores = getOption("mc.cores", 2L), 
                      mc.cleanup = TRUE, mc.allow.recursive = TRUE,
                      affinity.list = NULL, stop.on.error=FALSE) 
{
    stop.on.error <- stop.on.error[1]        #!!
    stopifnot(is.logical(stop.on.error))     #!!
    cores <- as.integer(mc.cores)
    if ((is.na(cores) || cores < 1L) && is.null(affinity.list)) 
        stop("'mc.cores' must be >= 1")
    parallel:::.check_ncores(cores)
    if (parallel:::isChild() && !isTRUE(mc.allow.recursive)) 
        return(lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...))
    if (!is.vector(X) || is.object(X)) 
        X <- as.list(X)
    if (!is.null(affinity.list) && length(affinity.list) < length(X)) 
        stop("affinity.list and X must have the same length")
    if (mc.set.seed) 
        mc.reset.stream()
    if (length(X) < 2) {
        old.aff <- mcaffinity()
        mcaffinity(affinity.list[[1]])
        res <- lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...)
        mcaffinity(old.aff)
        return(res)
    }
    if (length(X) < cores) 
        cores <- length(X)
    if (cores < 2L && is.null(affinity.list)) 
        return(lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...))
    jobs <- list()
    parallel:::prepareCleanup()
    on.exit(parallel:::cleanup(mc.cleanup))
    if (!mc.preschedule) {
        FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
        if (length(X) <= cores && is.null(affinity.list)) {
            jobs <- lapply(seq_along(X), function(i) mcparallel(FUN(X[[i]], 
                ...), name = names(X)[i], mc.set.seed = mc.set.seed, 
                silent = mc.silent))
            res <- mccollect(jobs)
            if (length(res) == length(X)) 
                names(res) <- names(X)
            has.errors <- sum(sapply(res, inherits, "try-error"))
        }
        else {
            sx <- seq_along(X)
            res <- vector("list", length(sx))
            names(res) <- names(X)
            fin <- rep(FALSE, length(X))
            if (!is.null(affinity.list)) {
                cores <- max(unlist(x = affinity.list, recursive = TRUE))
                d0 <- logical(cores)
                cpu.map <- lapply(sx, function(i) {
                  data <- d0
                  data[as.vector(affinity.list[[i]])] <- TRUE
                  data
                })
                ava <- do.call(rbind, cpu.map)
            }
            else {
                ava <- matrix(TRUE, nrow = length(X), ncol = cores)
            }
            jobid <- integer(cores)
            for (i in 1:cores) {
                jobid[i] <- match(TRUE, ava[, i])
                ava[jobid[i], ] <- FALSE
            }
            if (anyNA(jobid)) {
                unused <- which(is.na(jobid))
                jobid <- jobid[-unused]
                ava <- ava[, -unused, drop = FALSE]
            }
            jobs <- lapply(jobid, function(i) mcparallel(FUN(X[[i]], 
                ...), mc.set.seed = mc.set.seed, silent = mc.silent, 
                mc.affinity = affinity.list[[i]]))
            jobsp <- parallel:::processID(jobs)
            has.errors <- 0L
            delivered.result <- 0L
            while (!all(fin)) {
                s <- parallel:::selectChildren(jobs[!is.na(jobsp)], -1)
                if (is.null(s)) 
                  break
                if (is.integer(s)) 
                  for (ch in s) {
                    ji <- match(TRUE, jobsp == ch)
                    ci <- jobid[ji]
                    r <- parallel:::readChild(ch)
                    if (is.raw(r)) {
                      child.res <- unserialize(r)
                      if (inherits(child.res, "try-error")){
                          if(stop.on.error)                     #!!
                              stop("error in process X = ", ci, "\n", attr(child.res, "condition")$message) #!!
                          has.errors <- has.errors + 1L
                      }
                      if (!is.null(child.res)) 
                        res[[ci]] <- child.res
                      delivered.result <- delivered.result + 
                        1L
                    }
                    else {
                      fin[ci] <- TRUE
                      jobsp[ji] <- jobid[ji] <- NA
                      if (any(ava)) {
                        nexti <- which.max(ava[, ji])
                        if (!is.na(nexti)) {
                          jobid[ji] <- nexti
                          jobs[[ji]] <- mcparallel(FUN(X[[nexti]], 
                            ...), mc.set.seed = mc.set.seed, 
                            silent = mc.silent, mc.affinity = affinity.list[[nexti]])
                          jobsp[ji] <- parallel:::processID(jobs[[ji]])
                          ava[nexti, ] <- FALSE
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
            }
            nores <- length(X) - delivered.result
            if (nores > 0) 
                warning(sprintf(ngettext(nores, "%d parallel function call did not deliver a result", 
                  "%d parallel function calls did not deliver results"), 
                  nores), domain = NA)
        }
        if (has.errors) 
            warning(gettextf("%d function calls resulted in an error", 
                has.errors), domain = NA)
        return(res)
    }
    if (!is.null(affinity.list)) 
        warning("'mc.preschedule' must be false if 'affinity.list' is used")
    sindex <- lapply(seq_len(cores), function(i) seq(i, length(X), 
        by = cores))
    schedule <- lapply(seq_len(cores), function(i) X[seq(i, length(X), 
        by = cores)])
    ch <- list()
    res <- vector("list", length(X))
    names(res) <- names(X)
    cp <- rep(0L, cores)
    fin <- rep(FALSE, cores)
    dr <- rep(FALSE, cores)
    inner.do <- function(core) {
        S <- schedule[[core]]
        f <- parallel:::mcfork()
        if (isTRUE(mc.set.seed)) 
            parallel:::mc.advance.stream()
        if (inherits(f, "masterProcess")) {
            on.exit(mcexit(1L, structure("fatal error in wrapper code", 
                class = "try-error")))
            if (isTRUE(mc.set.seed)) 
                parallel:::mc.set.stream()
            if (isTRUE(mc.silent)) 
                closeStdout(TRUE)
            parallel:::sendMaster(try(lapply(X = S, FUN = FUN, ...), silent = TRUE))
            parallel:::mcexit(0L)
        }
        jobs[[core]] <<- ch[[core]] <<- f
        cp[core] <<- parallel:::processID(f)
        NULL
    }
    job.res <- lapply(seq_len(cores), inner.do)
    ac <- cp[cp > 0]
    has.errors <- integer(0)
    while (!all(fin)) {
        s <- parallel:::selectChildren(ac[!fin], -1)
        if (is.null(s)) 
            break
        if (is.integer(s)) 
            for (ch in s) {
                a <- parallel:::readChild(ch)
                if (is.integer(a)) {
                  core <- which(cp == a)
                  fin[core] <- TRUE
                }
                else if (is.raw(a)) {
                  core <- which(cp == attr(a, "pid"))
                  job.res[[core]] <- ijr <- unserialize(a)
                  if (inherits(ijr, "try-error")){ 
                    has.errors <- c(has.errors, core)
                    if(stop.on.error)  #!!
                        stop("error in one of X = ", paste(schedule[[core]], collapse=", "), "\n", attr(ijr, "condition")$message) #!!
                  }
                  dr[core] <- TRUE
                }
                else if (is.null(a)) {
                  core <- which(cp == ch)
                  fin[core] <- TRUE
                }
            }
    }
    for (i in seq_len(cores)) {
        this <- job.res[[i]]
        if (inherits(this, "try-error")) {
            for (j in sindex[[i]]) res[[j]] <- this
        }
        else if (!is.null(this)) 
            res[sindex[[i]]] <- this
    }
    nores <- cores - sum(dr)
    if (nores > 0) 
        warning(sprintf(ngettext(nores, "scheduled core %s did not deliver a result, all values of the job will be affected", 
            "scheduled cores %s did not deliver results, all values of the jobs will be affected"), 
            paste(which(dr == FALSE), collapse = ", ")), domain = NA)
    if (length(has.errors)) {
        if (length(has.errors) == cores) 
            warning("all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code")
        else warning(sprintf(ngettext(has.errors, "scheduled core %s encountered error in user code, all values of the job will be affected", 
            "scheduled cores %s encountered errors in user code, all values of the jobs will be affected"), 
            paste(has.errors, collapse = ", ")), domain = NA)
    }
    res
}
```

Tests:

```
f <- function(x, errorAt=1, sleep=2){
    if(x==errorAt) stop("-->> test error <<--")
    Sys.sleep(sleep)
    x
}

options(mc.cores=2)              
Mclapply(X=1:4, FUN=f, stop.on.error=TRUE)
## Error in Mclapply(X = 1:4, FUN = f, stop.on.error = TRUE) : 
##   error in one of X = 1, 3
## -->> test error <<--

Mclapply(X=1:4, FUN=f, errorAt=3, stop.on.error=TRUE)
## Error in Mclapply(X = 1:4, FUN = f, errorAt = 3, stop.on.error = TRUE) : 
##   error in one of X = 1, 3
## -->> test error <<--

Mclapply(X=1:4, FUN=f, errorAt=Inf, stop.on.error=TRUE)
## [[1]]
## [1] 1
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] 2
##
## [[3]]
## [1] 3
## 
## [[4]]
## [1] 4

Mclapply(X=1:4, FUN=f, mc.preschedule=FALSE, stop.on.error=TRUE)
## Error in Mclapply(X = 1:4, FUN = f, mc.preschedule = FALSE, stop.on.error = TRUE) : 
##   error in process X = 1
## -->> test error <<--

Mclapply(X=1:4, FUN=f, errorAt=3, mc.preschedule=FALSE, stop.on.error=TRUE)
## Error in Mclapply(X = 1:4, FUN = f, errorAt = 3, mc.preschedule = FALSE,  : 
##   error in process X = 3
## -->> test error <<--

Mclapply(X=1:4, FUN=f, errorAt=Inf, mc.preschedule=FALSE, stop.on.error=TRUE)
## [[1]]
## [1] 1
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] 2
##
## [[3]]
## [1] 3
## 
## [[4]]
## [1] 4
```

This approach uses many internal functions of the package **parallel** (e.g., `parallel:::isChild()`). It worked with R version 3.6.0.

Comment: hi florian---can you recommend this to the R core team?  I would think that this behavior is what most users prefer.

Answer (score 4):

Terminating the evaluations in all processes of a cluster upon an error in one process is not possible with a standard `mclapply()` call. The reason for this is that the processes do not communicate among each other until they are done.

Using the R package **future** one can achieve such a behavior. The idea is to

1. create futures and evaluate them in parallel
2. check every 2 seconds if one feature is resolved into an error
3. if an error is detected, kill all process of the cluster

A sketch how this could work:

```
library(future)
library(parallel)
library(tools)

parallelLapply <- function(x, fun, checkInterval=2, nProcess=2){ 

    ## setup cluster and get process IDs of process in cluster
    cl <- makeCluster(spec=nProcess)
    pids <- unlist(parLapply(cl=cl, X=1:nProcess, function(x) Sys.getpid()))
    plan(cluster, workers=cl)

    ## create futures and start their evaluation 
    fList <- lapply(1:2, function(x) futureCall(function(x) try(fun(x), silent=TRUE), list(x=x)))

    ## check every 2 second whether an error occurred or whether all are resolved
    while(TRUE){
        Sys.sleep(checkInterval)

        ## check for errors
        errorStatus <- unlist(lapply(fList, function(x)
            resolved(x) && class(value(x))=="try-error"))
        if(any(unlist(errorStatus))){
            lapply(pids, pskill)
            results <- NULL
            cat("an error occurred in one future: all process of the cluster were killed.\n")
            break
        }

        ## check if all resolved without error
        allResolved <- all(unlist(lapply(fList, resolved)))
        if(allResolved){
            results <- lapply(fList, value)
            cat("all futures are resolved sucessfully.\n")
            break
        }
    }
    results
}

## test 1: early termination because x=1 results in an error. 
f1 <- function(x){
    if(x==1) stop()
    Sys.sleep(15)
    x
}
parallelLapply(x=1:5, fun=f1)
# an error occurred in one future: all process of the cluster were killed.
# NULL


## test 2: no error 
f2 <- function(x){
    Sys.sleep(15)
    x
}
parallelLapply(x=1:5, fun=f2)
## all futures are resolved sucessfully.
## [[1]]
## [1] 1
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] 2
```

Note:

- Additional adjustment are needed if the function passed to `fun` depends on additional arguments.
- On Linux one can use `makeForkCluster()` instead of `makeCluster()` for convenience. Then the usage is closer to `mclapply()`.

Comment: yikes.  painful.  My need is only local `mclapply`, not a full cluster.  Alas, every time a process finishes one task, it goes back and requests another task.  At this point, the scheduler could remember that one of its processes has aborted already, and hand out no more tasks.  I guess I could simulate it by having each task check a global shared variable, but this seems slow and ugly.  Then again, it is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a cleaner version of the suggestion from ivo Welch. Note that this **does not stop running processes** when an error occurs, but rather **prevents the start of new evaluations of** `FUN`.

```
library(parallel)
mcLapply <- function(X, FUN, ..., mc.preschedule=TRUE,
                     mc.set.seed=TRUE, mc.silent=FALSE,
                     mc.cores=getOption("mc.cores", 2L), 
                     mc.cleanup=TRUE, mc.allow.recursive=TRUE,
                     affinity.list=NULL){
    tmpFileName <- tempfile()
    fn <- function(X){
        if(file.exists(tmpFileName))
            return(NA)
        o <- try(do.call("FUN", c(X, list(...))), silent=TRUE)
        if(class(o)=="try-error"){
            file.create(tmpFileName)
        }
        o
    }
    ret <- mclapply(X=X, FUN=fn, mc.preschedule=mc.preschedule,
                    mc.set.seed=mc.set.seed, mc.silent=mc.silent,
                    mc.cores=mc.cores, mc.cleanup=mc.cleanup,
                    mc.allow.recursive=mc.allow.recursive,
                    affinity.list=affinity.list)
    if(exists(tmpFileName))
        file.remove(tmpFileName)
    ret
}

## test 1: early termination because x=1 results in an error. 
f1 <- function(x){
    if(x==1) stop()
    Sys.sleep(1)
    x
}
mcLapply(X=1:3, FUN=f1)
## [[1]]
## [1] "Error in FUN(1L) : \n"
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "try-error"
## attr(,"condition")
## <simpleError in FUN(1L): >
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] NA
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] NA

## test 2: no error 
f2 <- function(x, a){
    Sys.sleep(1)
    x+a
}
mcLapply(X=1:2, FUN=f2, a=10)
## [[1]]
## [1] 11
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] 12
```

Comment: thanks, florian.  much nicer.  it's a pity that the master cannot also send a SIGINT to all its children.  but it's better than nothing.

Comment: It could be possible to kill the child processes with `parallel::mckill()`. Probably one can modify `parallel::mclapply()` to get the described behavior...

Comment: how?  I don't see a parallel::mckill().  Heck, I don't even know how to find the process-id's of all spawned processes.

Answer (score 0):

The following is ugly, but workable.  It uses the filesystem as a global shared variable.

```
options( mc.cores=2 )

if (!exists("touchFile"))
    touchFile <- function(filename) { system(paste0("touch ", filename)); }

tfnm <- paste0("mytemporary",as.numeric(Sys.time()))

mfun <- function( i ) {
    if (file.exists( tfnm )) stop("done due to process ", i)
    message("Mfun(", i,")")
    if ( i == 3 ) { message("creating ", tfnm); touchFile(tfnm); stop("goodbye"); }
    Sys.sleep( i%%3 )
}

v <- mclapply( 1:10, mfun )
if (file.exists(tfnm)) file.remove(tfnm)
```

This would be nicer to implement by mclapply itself.

Comment: This could be helpful in some cases. But it does **not** stop (possibly long) processes that are already running.